# Devo criar um container para cada site/app ou posso colocar todos em um mesmo?

Tags: docker

Estou começando a estudar o Docker, tenho brincado um pouco num servidor VPS que eu tenho, mas ainda persistem alguma duvidas.

Já entendi que é uma boa prática separar em containers o banco de dados e o sistema em si, mas devo criar um container para cada site que eu quiser hospedar ou posso simplesmente criar um container com apache e PHP e rodar vários sites lá dentro, mas fazendo o link com o container mysql?

Sei que a duvida pode ser meio básica, mas é que esse conceito não ficou muito claro

Comment: Pode das 2 formas. O que determina isso é a própria razão de você usar ou não um container. Você quem escolhe o que separar e o que não, de acordo com suas necessidades. Antes de mais nada, você realmente precisa de um container? Por outro lado, se é só exercício, faça versão separada e teste, e faça versão sem separar e teste. Assim você passa a saber fazer dos 2 (ou mais) jeitos. Da forma como está a pergunta, é uma questão de opinião, mas talvez com um clique no [edit] pondo mais detalhes da necessidade real (ou hipotética, no caso) talvez fique possível alguma resposta objetiva.

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver pensando em boas práticas, sim, cada site em um container. 
Isso para que você se beneficie de fato do isolamento, e garanta assim que um não impacte o outro, além de conseguir monitorar e isolar o consumo de recursos individualmente, inclusive te resguardando caso haja um eventual downtime.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo essa criação apartada, pois também existe a possibilidade de você conseguir reaproveitar algum container já criado, para subir apenas um site específico você pode trabalhar com o docker-composer e assim isolar os sites em diversos composers.